# How to compare two arrays or strings in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a array1 from checkboxes selected, and i need to compare with the most similar, how i do that?

```
var array1 = ["pain", "fever", "vomit"]


var array2 = ["diarrhea", "fever", "vomit", "embolism", "bleeding"]
var array3 = ["diarrhea", "tumor", "vomit", "cold", "bleeding"]
```

I tried some methods but they only return me as "true" or "false", I would like to get the most similar array1

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: "I tried some methods" - please **[edit]** the question and include your tries.

Comment: work on comparing COUNT OF MAXIMUM REPEATING NUMBER(or your string)  and then use your logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could count the number of similar elements using [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), then order your arrays by similarity and take the first element:

```js
const array1 = ["pain", "fever", "vomit"];

const array2 = ["diarrhea", "fever", "vomit", "embolism", "bleeding"];
const array3 = ["diarrhea", "tumor", "vomit", "cold", "bleeding"];

const countSimilarElements = (arr1, arr2) => arr1.reduce((count, x) => count + arr2.includes(x), 0);

const orderBySimilarity = (arr1, ...arr) =>
  arr.map(x => ({ array: x, similarity: countSimilarElements(arr1, x) }))
     .sort((a, b) => b.similarity - a.similarity);

const ordered = orderBySimilarity(array1, array2, array3);
console.log(ordered);
console.log(ordered[0].array);
```

Comment: Thank you! exactly what I was needing!

Answer (score 0):

This function takes in a the array you want to compare as the '*base*' and a list of other arrays as '*arr_list*', then returns a **similarity** array showing how **similar** each array in '*arr_list*' was to the '*base*'. This way you can **compare multiple arrays** with a single call and know reference their similarity by referencing the **index** of the returned **similarity** array.

```
const a = ['11', '22', '33'], b = ['11', '44', '55', '66'], c = ['55', '33', '11', '22'], d = ['11', '66', '44', '22'];

const Similarity = (base, arr_list) => {
    let similarity = new Array(arr_list.length).fill(0);//creates similarity array which defaults to 0
    base.forEach( el => {
        arr_list.forEach( (arr, i) => similarity[i] += arr.includes(el) )
    });
    return similarity;
}
const similarity = Similarity(a, [b,c,d])
console.log(similarity)
```